# Checking if number is ugly

Tags: java

I'm doing this problem:

> Write a program to check whether a given number is an ugly number.
>
> Ugly numbers are positive numbers whose prime factors only include 2, 3, 5. For example, 6, 8 are ugly while 14 is not ugly since it includes another prime factor 7.
>
> Note that 1 is typically treated as an ugly number.

Here's my attempt:

```
public class Solution {
    public boolean isUgly(int num) {
        if (num == 1) {
            return true;
        }
        for (int i = 7; i <= num / 2; i++) {
            if (isPrimeFactor(i, num)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isPrimeFactor(int candidate, int num) {
        return isPrime(candidate) && isFactor(candidate, num);
    }

    public boolean isPrime(int num) {
        if (num == 2) {
            return true;
        }
        if (num % 2 == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i += 2) {
            if (num % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isFactor(int candidate, int num) {
        return (num % candidate == 0);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it fails on test input -2147483648.  It returns true when it should be false.

Any idea what I've done wrong?

Comment: run your code through a debugger and tell us yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply forgot the following emphasized condition:

> Ugly numbers are **positive numbers** whose prime factors only include 2, 3, 5.

Therefore, you just need to add a check for negative numbers inside your `isUgly` method:

```
if (num <= 0) {
    return false;
}
```

---

As a side-note, you could perhaps improve a little the performance by swapping the conditions inside `isPrimeFactor` and testing `isFactor(candidate, num) && isPrime(candidate)` instead of `isPrime(candidate) && isFactor(candidate, num)`. This is because it is faster to determine whether a number is a factor of another than determining if a number is a prime number.

Answer (score 1):

I could propose a different but a lot faster solution O(logn) for this problem:

```
public static boolean isUgly(int num) {
    if (num < 1) return false;

    int temp;
    do {
        temp = num;
        if (num % 2 == 0) num /= 2;
        if (num % 3 == 0) num /= 3;
        if (num % 5 == 0) num /= 5; 
    } while (temp != num);

    return num == 1;
}
```

or an even faster approach in terms of modular checks (by splitting the `do while` loop):

```
public static boolean isUgly(int num) {
    if (num < 1) return false;

    int temp;
    do {
        temp = num;
        if (num % 2 == 0) num /= 2;
    } while (temp != num);
    do {
        temp = num;
        if (num % 3 == 0) num /= 3;
    } while (temp != num);
    do {
        temp = num;
        if (num % 5 == 0) num /= 5;
    } while (temp != num);

    return num == 1;
}
```